# Merging two CSV files using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation, pandas-datareader

I am trying to merge two different csv files using Pandas but am running into errors while doing so.

The first file is aapl.csv, which looks like this:

```
          Date   Close      High       Low      Open    Volume
Symbol                                                            
AAPL    2017-05-25  153.87  154.3500  153.0300  153.7300  19235598
AAPL    2017-05-26  153.61  154.2400  153.3100  154.0000  21927637
```

The second file is corr_column.csv, which looks like this:

```
Corr
0.01
0.02
```

I want to merge them in a way that 'Corr' shows up as a column after 'Volume'.

I have tried using pd.concat, as provided in the documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

This is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator, YearLocator, DayLocator
style.use( 'ggplot' )


##start = dt.datetime( 2017, 5, 29 )
##end = dt.datetime( 2018, 5, 29 )
##
##
##df = web.DataReader( AAPL, 'morningstar', start, end )
##
##df.to_csv( aapl.csv )

df = pd.read_csv( '/Users/zubairjohal/Documents/aapl.csv' ,         parse_dates=True, index_col=0 )
df_ohlc = df


corr_data = pd.read_csv( '/Users/zubairjohal/Documents/corr_column.csv', parse_dates=True, index_col=0 )


corr_data.dropna( inplace=True )


df.dropna( inplace=True )


merged = pd.concat( [ df, corr_data ], axis=1 )

merged.to_csv( 'combine2.csv', index=False )

print( merged )
```

However, while printing it, I am running into an error, as displayed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/zubairjohal/Documents/nw5.py", line 34, in <module>
merged = pd.concat( [ df, corr_data ], axis=1 )
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 226, in concat
return op.get_result()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py", line 423, in get_result
copy=self.copy)
File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-  packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 5425, in concatenate_block_managers
return BlockManager(blocks, axes)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3282, in __init__
self._verify_integrity()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 3493, in _verify_integrity
construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4843, in construction_error
passed, implied))
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 68896), indices imply (6, 514)
```

Any suggestion, reference or alternative would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
pd.concat([df_ohlc.reset_index(), corr_data], axis=1).set_index("Symbol")
```

outputs :

```
        Close        Date    High     Low    Open      Volume  Corr
Symbol                                                              
AAPL   153.87  2017-05-25  154.35  153.03  153.73  19235598.0  0.01
AAPL   153.61  2017-05-26  154.24  153.31  154.00  21927637.0  0.02
```

This works if your dataframes are in the way you printed them `df_ohlc` with AAPL as index and corr having no index.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I attempted your change but am getting a new error of  "Key Error: 'Index' ". I have checked and both these files have the same number of rows, i.e, 262. Any suggestions?

Comment: Actually, I apologize. While pasting the data, I missed out on a column heading. I have updated my post with how the df_ohlc data looks like. Please have a look @MohammedALANI

Comment: @zcdp I made an edit, just replace `index` by `Symbol`

Comment: @MohammedALANI, that does the work. Thanks! At the same time, if I have a csv file, similar to core_column, with the data as list instead of columns ( eg: [ 0.01, 0.02.....1.00 ], how can merging be done in that case?

Comment: @zcdp No worries ! Please validate my answer so people who have same issue as you will easily find the solution

Comment: Just transform the list into a column : df_corr = pd.DataFrame(); df_corr["corr"] = [0.01,...]